# How to remove rows if those don't match the head in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get rows from a very large text file which have same elements as the head using pandas. Eg.

Lets say I have a text file like the following

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6
7,8,9,10
```

where a, b, c and d are the head. In this case I don't know whether the second line is coming from column a or b or c or d. There is also no comma after number 6. Is there any way to remove those rows when reading to pandas database? or should I remove those rows before reading it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `error_bad_lines=False` to omit rows with more elements like header and [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove rows with less elements like number of header:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', error_bad_lines=False).dropna()

print (df)
   a  b    c     d
0  1  2  3.0   4.0
2  7  8  9.0  10.0
```

Preprocessing solution - create list for each row, test length with length of header and append to list of lists, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

Disadvantage is all values are strings, so necessary casting by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
import csv

out = []
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if (len(row) == len(header)):
            out.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=header).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   4
1  7  8  9  10
```

Or create list of rows with another lenghts like header and pass to `skiprows` parameter:

```
omit = []
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        if (len(row) != len(header)):
            omit.append(i)

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=omit)
print (df)
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   4
1  7  8  9  10
```